Highest theoretical threshold to fight single-qubit depolarizing noise for noiseless error-correction
Let's consider that each qubit in the lab faces a single-qubit depolarizing channel $\mathcal{N}(\rho)=(1-p) \rho + p \mathbb{I}/2$.
Is there a theoretical result indicating the largest value of $p$ such that quantum error-correction can completely suppress the effect of the noise asymptotically (by encoding the qubit in logical qubits composed of sufficiently many physical qubits).
In different terms: is the maximum theoretical threshold to fight depolarizing noise known?
I am assuming that the implementation of error-correction is noiseless here.

One way of defining the quantum capacity of a quantum channel $\mathcal{E}$ is to ask, asymptotically, as $n\to \infty$, how much quantum information can I send with error rate going to $0$ over $\mathcal{E}^{\otimes n}$?
For the family of depolarizing channels $$\mathcal{E}_p (\rho) = (1-p) \rho + \frac{p}{3} X\rho X + \frac{p}{3}Y \rho Y + \frac{p}{3}Z \rho Z$$
Your question is equivalent to asking for the largest $p$ such that the quantum capacity is positive. Call this $p^*$.
Unfortunately, the quantum capacity of the depolarizing channel is not known in closed form since the coherent information can be superadditive over multiple uses of the channel.** Lower bounds on $p^*$ by constructing coding schemes with a lower bound on their threshold.
Figure 7.1 in Graeme Smith's thesis plots some bounds on the capacity of the depolarizing channel



What we do know is the following:

$p^* < 1/4$ by a no-cloning argument
$p^* \ge .18929$ by a random coding argument (the "hashing bound")
$p^* \ge 0.19086$ by using a concatenated code that utilizes degeneracy (Smith-Smolin 2007)

** For the most extreme example, there are channels that individually have zero capacity but together have finite capacity

What is the no cloning argument that limits it to 25%? I ask because my understanding is that iterative entanglement purification, alternating between X-basis and Z-basis [2,1,2] repetition codes, should work for any amount of depolarizing noise less than 50%. At 50% it becomes impossible because the Bell pair is so depolarized that it can be prepared using LOCC.

Using this channel, only one-way classical communication is possible. Two-way is a different channel and indeed it is known to have finite capacity up to 1/2.

Ah, you're assuming the classical internet doesn't exist to assist the quantum channel. I always do analysis assuming the classical internet exists, because it does.

Both channels are reasonable to analyze, but for different reasons. I agree that for  communication, two-way is likely more realistic. However, this is a distinct channel, and one should be careful about which one is under consideration. For example, if I would like to store a qubit for some long time (without interacting with it**) and then return to it, depolarizing noise with one-way classical communication may be a reasonable model.
In the literature, "the depolarizing channel" frequently refers to one-way communication if not stated.
** Say, by shelving the state in a nuclear spin

Realistically, probably the zero-rate Hashing bound, so like 18-19%. Technically this could be violated? But I doubt by much.

If you assume the error correction to be noiseless and only consider a depolarizing channel on all qubits (say $p$ is the same on all qubits), then there will always be a probability of stabilizing a logical operator, this will be $\mathcal{O}(p^d)$, where $d$ is the code distance.
So if you are looking for the correction of an arbitrary number of errors, this will not be possible for any finite $p>0$.

Thanks for your answer. I know that with a finite number of qubits it is not possible. But asymptotically it is (for $d\to +\infty$).
